# Is there any way to access response / request details for the last executed Postman call

Tags: postman

Is there any way to access the response and request properties of the last run postman call using pm api's. In other words, does postman keep any historical log which is accessible till at least the last request.

Something like:
`pm.lastResponse.body` or `pm.lastRequest.Url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the response from the last call to an environment variable and get it on the next one

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

Comment: yes but i was hoping there could be an implicit way of accessing the last response so a particular request doesn't depend on creation of a specific envt variable from previous calls, since anyone can create any name for that variable if we are working in a big team that shares collections, lest we are looking forward to having a standard variable name enforced for all test script which might not be required in several cases to be captured,